# How to add sr no column in csv file in php

Tags: php, sql-server, csv

```
$filename = "Registrations.csv";
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$header = array("Sr No","FirstName","RegNo","Address","Contact","email");
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
fputcsv($fp, $header);  
$query = "select FirstName,RegNo,Address,Contact,email from  Registration";     
$result = mssql_query($query);
while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter -

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $row = array($i) + $row;
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
  $i++;
}
```

`$row = array($i) + $row;` OR `$row = array_merge(array($i), $row);`